# The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. React Admin. Golang api

Tags: reactjs, go, react-admin

I'm trying to create a admin panel using react-admin.
I'm trying to connect my api and react admin for the umpteenth time, but nothing works. The Content-Range header is missing in the HTTP Response. Although I think I'm doing everything right (I think so).

app.tsx:

```
import { Admin, Resource } from "react-admin";
import { UserList } from "./users";
import { dataProvider } from "./dataProvider";
import { MyLayout } from './MyLayout';

export const App = () => <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={MyLayout}>
  <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
</Admin>;
```

users.tsx:

```
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, EmailField } from "react-admin";

export const UserList = () => (
    <List>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="username" />
            <TextField source="first_name" />
            <TextField source="last_name" />
            <TextField source="position" />
            <TextField source="access_level" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

GO API:

CORS:

```
handler := cors.AllowAll().Handler(r)
log.Printf("Server is running on port %s...", port)
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, handler))
```

users:

```
func GetUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var users []api.User
    db.DB.Find(&users)

    totalResources := len(users)

    // Content-Range
    w.Header().Set("Content-Range", fmt.Sprintf("items 0-%d/%d", totalResources-1, totalResources))

    userResponses := make([]UserResponse, 0)
    for _, user := range users {
        userResponses = append(userResponses, UserResponse{
            ID:          user.ID,
            Username:    user.Username,
            FirstName:   user.FirstName,
            LastName:    user.LastName,
            Position:    user.Position,
            AccessLevel: user.AccessLevel,
        })
    }

    respondWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, userResponses)
}
```

[[image]]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` anywhere in your code

Comment: i have cors.AllowAll or is that the wrong thing?

Comment: From where id getting dataProvider?

Comment: **https://marmelab.com/react-admin/fetchJson.html#adding-the-authorization-header** you should apply this method .

Comment: it is didnt help

Answer (score 2):

If you use a "simple REST client" then according to the documentation it expects a slightly different header format:
`'Content-Range', 'users 0-24/324'` // 'users' is the name of your resource

Comment: im try this code, but it is not work

 `w.Header().Set("Content-Range", fmt.Sprintf("users 0-%d/%d", totalResources-1, totalResources))`

Comment: Add information to your question about all current request and response headers.